# Does the 'generic blanket impl of ToString' conflict with the 'impl Tostring for char/str/String...' in rust

Tags: generics, rust, implementation

There is a generic blanket impl ToString for T,

```
impl<T> ToString for T where
    T: Display + ?Sized,
```

I also noticed `impl ToString for char/str/String`..., and for many other types in the library document https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#implementors.

Does it conflict with the generic blanket impl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously it doesn't conflict since it works ☺

But you're right, it *should* conflict. There is a feature under development called [*"specialization"*](https://uta8a.github.io/rust-rfc-with-ja-dict/1210-impl-specialization.html) which will enable the compiler to resolve conflicts when multiple `impl` exist provided one is more specific than the others. In this case, implementing for an explicit type (`char` or `String`) is more specific than any generic `impl<T> for T`, so it works.

This feature is not yet stable enough for general use, but a subset of it is considered good enough for use in the Rust standard library, as you can see in [the source code for `impl ToString for char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2284-2289):

```
#[stable(feature = "char_to_string_specialization", since = "1.46.0")]
impl ToString for char {
```